# Running Emacs through X2Go, the bidirectional clipboard does not work, even though it works for other programs

Tags: ssh, x11, remote, clipboard

Being in home-office due to the Corona outbreak, I am using Emacs and other programs through X2Go.

I am also running a terminal through GNU Screen in a MinTTY window, because scrolling the terminal for analyzing the output is very slow over X2Go.

I was running into the problem, that I couldn't copy/paste between the remote Emacs and other applications, native or remote.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the cause was having started Emacs as a tab of GNU Screen and connecting to it by `emacsclient`. After restarting Emacs from within the X2Go session, the bidirectional clipboard started working again.